# How to pass segue data in that case?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using SWReveal library to make a side bar menu. Now, I'm trying to implement two different  side bar menus in two different view controllers. All is working, except that I'm facing a problem passing data between the previous controller and the next controller having the different menu. Here is the case:
[image]

Reveal View Controller is receiving the segue from the previous VC, however, I want to pass data between the previous VC (before Reveal View Controller) and Today Competition DetailsVC.
Is that possible ?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TodayViewController is not instantiated, there´s no way you can send anything to it. 
You can send a message trough the other view controllers, and when one of them opens TodayVC,  send the message to it.

Another option is to saave the data in the NSUserDefaults of the app, and retrieve it later, like this¨:

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"valueName"];

NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"valueName"];
```

Comment: But the problem is neither Side BarVC or the "Navigation Controller" can intercept data. And in this case the most important is the Navigation Controller.

Comment: You can use NSNotifications then

Comment: A variable is NSNotifications is like a "global variable" ?

Comment: It´s just a notification. If you want to use global variable you can use NSUserDefaults, I´ll edit my answer

Comment: So I think in that case I'll better use NSUserDefaults instead of NSNotifications.